# Cannot convert BinaryReader.PeekChar or ReadChar to String C#

Tags: c#

Whenever I try to convert `BinaryReader` `PeekChar` or `ReadChar` to string it gives me an error

> Error 1   'System.IO.BinaryReader.PeekChar()' is a 'method', which is
>   not valid in the given context

How do I convert it? Here is my code sample:

```
 private void openTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myPath = textBox3.Text;
        BinaryReader objBinReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(myPath, FileMode.Open));
        listBox1.Hide();
        richTextBox1.Show();

        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        do
        {

            try
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + objBinReader.ReadChar.toString();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(objBinReader.PeekChar.toString());
            }
        } while (objBinReader.PeekChar.toString() != "-1");

        objBinReader.Close();

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you are trying to use a method as if it were a property

Comment: Next compilation error will be that `toString()` doesn't exist. The method is called `ToString()`

Comment: PeekChar returns an int, not a `Char`. You'll have to cast it to `Char` before using it, otherwise you'll get a string with the numerica value

Comment: maby you should fixe some more problems (putting your binary reader in a using block, using a StringBuilder instead of string concatination since string is immutable)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `()` for the method calls

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + objBinReader.ReadChar().ToString();
```

and

```
objBinReader.PeekChar().ToString()
```

Comment: `toString()` will be the next compilation error *and* result in unexpected results - `PeekChar` returns an int

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you're reading the file `char` after `char`. Why not do it in one (easy) go?

```
 private void openTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     listBox1.Hide();

     richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBox3.Text);

     richTextBox1.Show();
 }
```

An alternative solution with BinaryReader will be

```
 private void openTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     listBox1.Hide();

     // when building string in a loop use StringBuilder
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

     // do not close BinaryReader manually, put using instead 
     using (BinaryReader objBinReader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(textBox3.Text)))
     {
         // PeekChar() is a method, notice () 
         while (objBinReader.PeekChar() != -1) 
             sb.Append(objBinReader.ReadChar()); // ReadChar() is a method as well
     } 

     richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
     richTextBox1.Show();
 }
```

Comment: maby 'caus the file is a binary file? *just asking*

Comment: @Radinator: every file can be treated as text one (it will be a weird text, however, for real binary files like dll, exe); the code in the question uses `PeekChar`, `ReadChar`, not `PeekByte` and `ReadByte`, so it's a clear attempt (for me, at least) to read the file as text.